# How to move object towards an angle in degrees? (C, C++)

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to move a bullet object towards a player position. I found this angle function online, and it seems to convert it to those coordinates in the comments. But i can't make the bullet follow in the direction.

```
float Angle(int p1x, int p1y, int p2x,int p2y)
{
    //Make point1 the origin, make point2 relative to the origin so we do point1 - point1, and point2-point1,
    //since we dont need point1 for the equation to work, the equation works correctly with the origin 0,0.
    int deltaY = p2y - p1y;
    int deltaX = p2x - p1x; //Vector 2 is now relative to origin, the angle is the same, we have just transformed it to use the origin.

    float angleInDegrees = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI;
    //float angleInRadians = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

    angleInDegrees *= -1; // Y axis is inverted in computer windows, Y goes down, so invert the angle.

    //Angle returned as:
    //                      90
    //            135                45
    //
    //       180          Origin           0
    //
    //           -135                -45
    //
    //                     -90


    return angleInDegrees;
    
}


  if (bulletsData[3] == STDEACTIVE){ //bulletData: 0 = x, 1 = y, 2 = dir, 3 = state
      
      bulletsData[2] = Angle(bulletsData[0],bulletsData[1], plData[0], plData[1]);
      bulletsData[3] = STACTIVE;
          
  }


  if (bulletsData[3] == STACTIVE){

      if (ardu.everyXFrames(1)){
        
          bulletsData[0] += cos(bulletsData[2]) * 1; //My attempt to move it towards the direction.
          bulletsData[1] += sin(bulletsData[2]) * 1;
          
      }
      
  }
```

Comment: If this is C++, why not make a simple vector structure or tuple instead of passing in so many arguments?

Comment: Worth looking at [GNU Exterior Ballistics Computer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/balcomp/) which has a great short and concise ballistics function you may want to adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly calculating angles in degrees, yet `sin` and `cos` expect radians, not degrees.

Without analyzing whether or not the `Angle` function is correct, your code will make more sense if you change the function to return a value in radians.  You even have the required line there commented out.

So, something like this perhaps:

```
float angleInRadians = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
return -angleInRadians;  // Return negative angle to compensate for Y-down
```

Comment: Yes that gives me radiants, and it does not solve the angle issue though. If the player is to the bottom-right for example, it just shoots it to the right direction. off about 25 degrees.

Comment: Someone else mentioned in the comments earlier (and then deleted it) that it's possible your array `bulletsData` is an integer type.  Perhaps that is the issue.  If you truncate a radian value to integer, your results will be horrible.

Comment: You don't actually need trig functions for this problem, by the way.  The standard way to do it is using vectors.  A vector from A to B is (B - A), or (dx, dy) where (`dx = Bx-Ax`, `dy = By-Ay`).  The length of the vector is `len = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)` -- this the Pythagorean triangle rule.  Thus, the normalized vector is (`dx / len`, `dy / len`), which is essentially what you're trying to do here using `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: Yes the issue was indeed i truncated the radian value. I switch them to float and it seems to work. But now that it travels correctly, when it reaches end point of the  target, it skews away in a different angle from where it was heading. This is the snippet i added to make it work when the y axis is bellow the bullet or above.           if (plData[1] > bulletsData[1]) {
            bulletsData[0] += cos(bulletsData[2] + 180) * 1;
          }else{
            bulletsData[0] += cos(bulletsData[2] - 180) * 1;
          }

Comment: It's good to hear that you have resolved your issue.